# Want label to display on ball collision in cocos2d and box2d application

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I'm using _world->step(dt,5,5) to detect the collision system. So collision is actually getting handled by box2d classes. Now I want to show score on balls collision depending on to which ball it has collide?

Can any one please help me out with this? If you guys want I can provide source code of tick function if required.

Your help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Ankita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a fixture for each body and in tick function check for collision...

```
if((contact.fixtureA == fixture1 && contact.fixtureB == fixture2) ||
(contact.fixtureA == fixture2 && contact.fixtureB == fixture1))
{
//do something
}
```

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually collision is already getting handled inside the box2d. I didn't need to develop. But what i need is whenever it collide it should show label. And I can not understand actually which function will handle this. Because Collission.cpp is box2D class and _world->step is actually doing everything. Makes sense?

Comment: I think.You are creating body like this fd->createFixture(body) in box2d.Assign this into a b2Fixture.i.e., fixture1 = fd->createFixture(body).For each body you have to assign with fixture and in tick method,Use the above code for checking collision of bodies.(here collision is detected for finding which two fixture is colliding).

Comment: Anish, step method already handles collision. I just need help with showing label to show score using step method. Is it clear?

Comment: It is not for collision.It is for finding which two bodies are colliding.So you can increase your score based on the corresponding body collision.Clear?????

Answer (score 1):

First, subclass the C++ class b2ContactListener, for example:

```
class GamePhysicsContactListener : public b2ContactListener 
{
public:
    GamePhysicsContactListener();   
    ~GamePhysicsContactListener();  
    void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse);

};
```

Implement the `PostSolve` method to do the checking on the two bodies that are in contact by using:

```
b2Body *bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
b2Body *bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
```

And finally, instantiate the listener by calling the line below in the method where you instantiate your `b2World` (most probably in your CCLayer `init` method):

```
_world->SetContactListener(new GamePhysicsContactListener());
```

p/s: instead of doing the contact checking logic in the GamePhysicsContactListener class, you can also make that class to accept a target and a selector to be invoked using NSInvocation. That would be a bit more complex though.

EDIT:

Here is the working implementation of GamePhysicsContactListener: https://gist.github.com/922824 (it's part of my private GamePhysics framework that bridges Cocos2D & Box2D classes)

Comment: @Lukman: Thanks for your reply. Actually collision is already getting handled inside the box2d. I didn't need to develop. But what i need is whenever it collide it should show label. And I can not understand actually which function will handle this. Because Collission.cpp is box2D class and _world->step is actually doing everything. Makes sense?

Comment: you are right that _world->step is already doing the collision detection but that is only to handle the movement of the bodies, e.g. bodies reflect against each other. But if you need the box2d to tell you which bodies are actually colliding at a certain time, you need to set a contact listener, hence you need to use codes similar to the one I posted. That is where you put your logic that might look like `if (body1 == ballBody && body2 == goalBody) { [self increaseScore]; }` etc.

Comment: (continue because comment limit) In this case you don't have to put anything in the tick method because box2d will call your contact listener as and when collisions happen.

Comment: @Lukman: Thanks, that sounds like it should work. When I tried to create the class and create listener, it is throwing symbol(s) not declared linking error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you implement the class? Because the code i gave in the first block is just the class declaration (.h file). You'll need the class implementation (.mm file) as well

Comment: Yes I did. But it still shows the same error and if i copy it's definition to .h file then it says duplicate declaration of postsolve. I made method as virtual still it doesn't work :(

Comment: ACtually whenenver I'm adding "_world->SetContactListener(new GamePhysicsContactListener());" this line it throws and error for undefined symbol.

Comment: Then I tried creating object, it works for creating of object but when i say obj = new GamePhysicsContactListener(); It throws an error. Any Idea?

Comment: @Lukam:  I got it. I didn't write definition of all function. I wrote it and it complied. But now it's not going into the postSolve method. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: Did you do `_world->SetContactListener(new GamePhysicsContactListener());`? Try putting some `NSLog` in the PostSolve method.

Comment: @Lukam: Can't we use beginContact instead of PostSolve method. I recognised all collisions in beginContact method and it works fine. However, I have the same problem as that of Ankita. I am unable to display label on collision. I have explained it in my answer (rather a question :D). I have also posted similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894119/display-text-on-collision-box2d).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I'm using to show a little animation upon collision. It could be pretty easily modified to show a label instead of an animation.

```
-(void) paintCollisionImage:(CGPoint) point{

CGSize screenSize = self.view.bounds.size;

CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake((point.x -24), ((screenSize.height - point.y) -24), 48.0f, 48.0f);

NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"collideImage0.png"], 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"collideImage1.png"], 
                     nil];
UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc]; 

[myAnimatedView initWithFrame:myImageRect]; 
myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages; 
myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 0.25; // seconds 
myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 1; // 0 = loops forever 

[myAnimatedView startAnimating]; 
[self.view addSubview:myAnimatedView]; 
[myAnimatedView release];
```

}

I call it like so:

```
[self paintCollisionImage:collisionPoint];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I wanted to display a label when the player hits a power. For this I created a static function in CCScene which adds a label on the scene. And in the ContactListener I initialized the scene object in beginContact method and then called the scene function.

```
+(void)addPointLabel  
{  
    DataClass *d5=[DataClass getInstance];  
   [_label setString:@"+10"];        // Define label in init  
    _label.color = ccc3(0,255,0);  
    _label.position = ccp(d5.playerXPosition,d5.playerYPosition);  
    [self addChild:_label];  
    d5.lbl=_label;  
    id action1 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(d5.playerXPosition,d5.playerYPosition+20)];  
    id action2 = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1.0f];  
    [_label runAction: [CCSequence actions:action1,action2,  nil]];    
}
```

Now call this method in your ContactListener class :

```
[GameScene addPointLabel];
```